# Can we show the managed metadata columns which are defined inside our document library in Windows explorer

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, managed-metadata

I have a document library inside a SharePoint online site collection, and the document library has 5 managed metadata columns, now when viewing the documents inside the SharePoint list view i can show the 5 managed metadata. but if i chose to view the documents inside Windows Explorer , then the managed metadata will not be shown, so is there a way to show the managed metadata columns inside windows explorer as well (as in the list view case)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported to add custom columns in SharePoint (including managed metadata columns) to File Explorer.

In fact, File Explorer does not accept custom columns in any way. So it is not possible to achieve this requirement.

You can see the post below for related discussion:

[What SharePoint library columns might be recognized as columns (details/fields) in File Explorer?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/what-sharepoint-library-columns-might-be-recognized-as-columns/m-p/148968)

Comment: @ok thanks for the info